# Why an autowired instance is not being called from private method?

Tags: java, spring, autowired

Suppose I have a componenet class inside that I have autowired a service class. like

```
@Autowired

private MyService myService;
```

and then if I want to use it from a private method from same class like,

```
private void callService(){

    myService.servmMthod();

}
```

It will give us a null pointer since myService is null here but it will be alright if method is public like below

```
public void callService(){

    myService.servmMthod();

}
```

Could you please explain why it behaves like that?

Based on the comment:

```
@Component
public class MyDemo {
    @Autowired
    private MyService myService;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
                "spring.xml");
        Customer c1 = null;
        MyDemo myDemo = ctx.getBean(MyDemo.class);
        myDemo.callService(ctx);
    }

    private void callService(ApplicationContext ctx) {
        System.out.println(myService);
        myService.callMydao();
    }
}
```

if `callService` is public its working fine else `myService` is null.

Comment: Do you have a getter and setter for myService? put @Autowired  annotation in there also.

Comment: show us the whole class, from where you are calling your private method.

Comment: I think you are not focusing on the right aspect. A field either does or doesn't have a value, it has nothing to do with what method you read it from. My guess: you are calling the private method from the constructor, or from another piece of code which executes too early into the bean lifecycle (before the properties were wired in). If not that, then there's a small chance you are doing something funky with concurrent access.

Comment: Can you share your code please?

Comment: Vishnudev K , No I dont have any setter and getter for myService

Answer (score 0):

I guess your `MyService` is using AOP, so that Spring use dynamic proxy to create a proxy of `MyDemo` class.

When the container scans the bean to generate the proxy class, the public methods can be proxyed, but the private method is not proxyed. The property injection is also done in the proxy class, so the injection property obtained by the public method is the injection.  Private method gets the attribute when the injection is not completed, so it is null.